# Travelling to Montenegro using a Blue Card

Tags: schengen, montenegro

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with travelling to Montenegro using the Blue Card?

I realize it's not a Schengen state but their travel regulations say the following:

> Holders of travel documents containing a valid Schengen visa, a valid visa of the United States of America or a permission to stay in
>   these countries, may enter and stay, i.e. pass through the territory
>   of Montenegro up to seven days, and not longer than the expiry of
>   visa, if the period of validity of visa is less than seven days.

I realize a Blue Card is a residence permit and not a travel document.

Do the rules apply to Blue Card holders as well?

Comment: Doesn't a Blue Card count as 'permission to stay'?

Comment: True. But I am uncomfortable with the wording of the paragraph. It says 'holders of **travel documents** containing.... permission to stay'

I am not sure if a blue card is a travel document.

Comment: @Omar The wording is ambiguous, but the only reasonable interpretation is that you either need 'a travel document with a valid visa' or completely independent from that 'a permission to stay'. Visas are usually affixed to your travel document, while at least the Schengen residence permits are usually issued as separate documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got on the phone with the Montenegro embassy in Berlin. They say that  anyone with a valid residence permit (aufenthaltstitel) for one of the Schengen countries can stay for a period of 30 days in Montenegro. Since a blue-card is a residence permit, the same rules apply but it's mandatory to carry your passport.

So, happy holidays to me!! :)